Strange "Can't guess meta-package" error message when run Software Updater
Ubuntu 22.04.4, GNOME 42.9, Wayland.
When I run the Software Updater, I started getting the series of three error messages as shown in the three attached screenshots:



When I run sudo apt update, it reports no errors, but does end by saying this: "4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them."
When I run sudo apt upgrade, it reports no errors, but does end by saying this: "The following packages have been kept back: libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin"
When I run sudo apt-get upgrade --with-new-pkgs for those four packages, here is the result:
main1@system1:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade --with-new-pkgs libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:


The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 chrome-gnome-shell : Depends: gnome-shell but it is not installable
 gdm3 : Depends: gnome-shell (>= 3.37.90) but it is not installable
 gnome-shell-extension-appindicator : Depends: gnome-shell (>= 3.33) but it is not installable
                                      Depends: gnome-shell (< 43~) but it is not installable
 gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng : Depends: gnome-shell (>= 3.38) but it is not installable
 gnome-shell-extension-prefs : Depends: gnome-shell (= 42.5-0ubuntu1pop1~1675984688~22.04~f574f54~dev) but it is not installable
 gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock : Depends: gnome-shell (< 43) but it is not installable
                                     Depends: gnome-shell (>= 40) but it is not installable
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: gnome-shell but it is not installable
 ubuntu-desktop-minimal : Depends: gnome-shell but it is not installable
 ubuntu-session : Depends: gnome-shell (>= 3.37.91) but it is not installable
E: Broken packages

But, chrome-gnome-shell, gnome-shell, ubuntu-desktop, etc., are all already installed and running just fine.
When I run Synaptic, it reports no broken packages.
Questions:

What are these Software Updater error messages shown in the screenshots above trying to tell me?
Are those Software Updater error messages related to the four libglib packages that are being held back?
Why does tyring to install those four libglib packages report that I have broken packages?
What should I be doing to fix whatever is wrong? (And, I do realize that one of the error messages above suggested using ppa-purge on some offending application, but I have no idea which application it is referring to.)

Thanks in advance for any help.
Update:  Here is the output of sudo apt update:
> main1@system1:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for main1: 
Hit:1 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                             
Hit:3 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                      
Hit:4 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                                                              
Ign:5 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge InRelease                                                               
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]                                                            
Hit:7 https://packages.element.io/debian default InRelease                                                                         
Hit:8 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge Release                                                                 
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]                                                          
Hit:10 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease                                                            
Get:12 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease [3,590 B]                                                        
Hit:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                                  
Hit:14 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease                                                                          
Hit:16 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/agornostal/ulauncher/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                
Hit:17 https://repo.waydro.id jammy InRelease                       
Hit:18 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/christian-boxdoerfer/fsearch-stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:11 https://packagecloud.io/filips/FirefoxPWA/any any InRelease
Hit:19 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/diesch/stable/ubuntu impish InRelease
Hit:20 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gerardpuig/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:21 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/kelebek333/mint-tools/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:22 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/nextcloud-devs/client/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:23 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ng-hong-quan/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease [18.3 kB]
Hit:24 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/system76-dev/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:25 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/teejee2008/timeshift/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:26 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntuhandbook1/menulibre/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Fetched 251 kB in 2s (104 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
main1@system1:~$


Please add the complete output of sudo apt update to your post. This will show us the sources referenced by your package system.

@OrganicMarble , I updated my original post at the top, I put the ouput of the sudo apt update command at the end of my original post.

Your sources list mixes sources for various Ubuntu releases (xenial, jammy, impish) and Debian releases. I don't know what is causing this specific issue but your package system is a mess.

@OrganicMarble , I identified the non-Jammy sources, and tracked down the applications installed from them.  I uninstalled and purged those applications, along with looking up how to remove their related source, whether via ppa-purge or some other method if not a ppa source.  At this point I have only seven ppa type repositories, all of them for the jammy version, along with five sources - Virtual box, Brave browser, Element, Firefox PWA, and ProtonVPN - that do not specify jammy or any ubuntu version.  But I still have the same problem as I originally described, don't know how to proceed.

Impressive work, that will serve you well going forward, if this problem can be resolved. If I had this problem, I would try using apt policy [packagename] on the packages listed in the error messages. That will tell you the versions of the installed packages and what source they came from. It may be a lengthy process because the listed packages may not be the culprits, it may be the ones listed as dependencies. But if you can find the source of the problem packages, or even that they are orphaned (no source), you should be able to install the proper versions. Maybe start w ubuntu-desktop?

@OrganicMarble , thanks, but maybe not impressive enough.  Before I could even try the things you suggested, just for giggles I ran sudo apt update - AGAIN, probably for the 100th time over the past five days - and suddenly there were 22 packages that needed updating.  With great trepidation I installed them, and what do you know?  My problems went away, everything is great now, no partial upgrade error messages, no held back packages that I cannot install, etc.  I have NO IDEA why all is okay now.  I wish I could go back and see what those 22 pacakge were, and understand what got corrected.

Great news! My guess is that cleaning up your sources list and removing packages from the "bad" sources fixed it. If you want to see what got updated, look in /var/log/apt/history.log
